# check folder name available or not with starting name of folder

Tags: php, regex

I have a folder named with "ABCDEF-GHIJK-LM" where "ABCDEF" is fixed and second two section are based on user entry and folder name starting with "ABCDEF" is unique i.e only one folder will start with ABCDEF.

Due to some logical reasons, I am unable to save complete folder name.
Can anyone please suggest how can I check if any folder is available starting with ABCDEF?

Note: Please ask if any data is required for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save complete folder name where? Save it how? You expect us to guess all this?

Comment: Hi @u_mulder thanks for your comment but I have not mention these because i thought it is not required and saving process is also not required as i have already a folder named "ABCDEF-GHIJK-LM". And it is not required to fetch the info.

Comment: The function glob() should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @jannej, yes the same I was looking for the same and I have implemented the answer by glob() function.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving the solutions and hints which helped me lot to find the solution for me and encouraged me @webmaster, #oliver, #jannej  and all.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
$path = 'path_to_search/';
$results = scandir($path);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

    if (is_dir($path . '/' . $result)) {
        if (substr( $result, 0, 6 ) === "ABCDEF") {
            //folder exists
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @webmaster please let me  check

Comment: @nishant did you check?

Comment: Yes it worked but since the main folder have too many folder  so it is taking time. I have also found a solution with help of @jannej hint and posted below. Thanks again.

Comment: Vaow, yes my code is poor on performance, so sorry for not thinking it. Very happy for you to find the real solution, thank you very much for your question. By the way, I do not understand people why they gave -2 to your question whereas it is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use php dir function (http://php.net/manual/de/function.dir.php):

```
<?php
$d = dir("/path/to/base/dir");
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  if (strpos($entry,'ABCDEF')===0) {
      // DIR FOUND, do what you want
      ...
      break;
  }
}
$d->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Oliver please let me check

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for you help and above answer also worked but I have found a simple solution for it and it is working correctly.

```
    $folderName='ABCDEF';   
    $fileInstaceFound = glob('fullFolderPath/'.$folderName.'-*');  
    if(empty($fileInstaceFound)){
        //  folder not found
    }else{
        //folder found
    }
```